# How to create a 2D Numpy array using a function on a 1D array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to write a function in Python using Numpy that would take as input a vector `x = array([x_1, x_2, ..., x_n])` and a positive integer `m` and return an array of dimension `n` by `m` of the form (say `n==3`, `m==4`):

```
array([[ x_1,   x_1^2,   x_1^3,   x_1^4],
       [ x_2,   x_2^2,   x_2^3,   x_2^4],
       [ x_3,   x_3^2,   x_3^3,   x_3^4]])
```

So far I have

```
import numpy as np
def f(x, m):
    return x ** np.arange(1, m+1)
```

which works fine for `n==1`, but raises an exception for `n > 1`.
I am trying to avoid using loops. Is there a nice way of making this in Numpy?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

1. Use `np.vander`

```
x = np.array([2.3,1.3,4.4])      
m = 4

np.vander(x,m+1,True)[:,1:]                                       
# array([[  2.3   ,   5.29  ,  12.167 ,  27.9841],
#        [  1.3   ,   1.69  ,   2.197 ,   2.8561],
#        [  4.4   ,  19.36  ,  85.184 , 374.8096]])
```

or

2. use `np.power.outer`

```
np.power.outer(x,np.arange(1,m+1))
#  same output
```

or

3. use `np.logspace`

```
np.logspace(1,m,m,True,x[:,None])
# same output
```

or

4. use `np.multply.accumulate` or `cumprod`

```
np.multiply.accumulate(np.broadcast_to(x,(m,np.size(x))),axis=0).T
# same output

np.broadcast_to(x,(m,np.size(x))).cumprod(axis=0).T
# same output
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use broadcasting for this:

```
def f(x, m):
    return x[:, np.newaxis] ** np.arange(1, m + 1)[np.newaxis, :]
```

This sets x as a shape (n, 1) vector, the range as a (1, m) vector, and has them interact in the way that you want.

Here's what it looks like in my IPython REPL.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: def f(x, m):
   ...:     return x[:, np.newaxis] ** np.arange(1, m + 1)[np.newaxis, :]
   ...: 

In [3]: x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

In [4]: f(x, 6)
Out[4]: 
array([[    1,     1,     1,     1,     1,     1],
       [    2,     4,     8,    16,    32,    64],
       [    3,     9,    27,    81,   243,   729],
       [    4,    16,    64,   256,  1024,  4096],
       [    5,    25,   125,   625,  3125, 15625]])
```